# Parsing HTML-attributes like strings

Tags: perl

Have strings like HTML attributes

```
key1="value1 value2" key2="va3" key4
```

need parse such string to get HoA:

```
$parsed = {
    key1' => [
                  'value1',
                  'value2'
             ],
    key2 => [ 'val3' ],    #or key2 => 'val3'  doesn't matter..
    key4 => undef,
};
```

Creating the function myself, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

while(<DATA>) {
    my $parsed;
    chomp;
    next if m/\A\s*#/;
    while( m/(\w+)(\s*=\s*(["'])(.*?)(\3))?/g ) {
        my $k = $1;
        if( $4 ) {
            my @v = split(/\s+/, $4);
            $parsed->{$k} = \@v;
        }
        else {
            $parsed->{$k} = undef;
        }
    }
    say Dumper $parsed;
}

__DATA__
key1="value1 value2" key2 key3="val3"
key1='value1 "value2"' key8 key3='val3'
key1='value1 i\'m' key2 key3="val3"
key1='value1 value2' key8 key3=val3
```

works and prints correct results for the first 2 lines.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'key1' => [
                      'value1',
                      'value2'
                    ],
          'key3' => [
                      'val3'
                    ],
          'key2' => undef
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'key1' => [
                      'value1',
                      '"value2"'
                    ],
          'key3' => [
                      'val3'
                    ],
          'key8' => undef
        };
```

Unfortunately, it fails on 3rd line - don't know how to handle the escaped quotes. (*And just figured out than the `key=val` (without quotes) is valid too))*

Additionally, because don't want reinvent the wheel again, probably exists some module on CPAN for this, only haven't any idea **what to search**. ;(

### EDIT

@mpapec suggested a module, what could greatly help for parsing the RHS part of the "assignement". My problem is than the string contains multiple space delimited `LHS=RHS`, where the RHS could be quoted (in single and double) or not quoted (in the case of one value) and the RHS values (in the quotes) are space delimited too..

```
key1="value1 value2" key2="va3" key4 key5=val5 key6='val6' key7='val x\'y zzz'
```

So I don't know how to break the string into multiple `LHS=RHS` parts, because can't split at space and can't use *my regex*, because it fails in escaped quotes. (maybe some more complicated regex what handles escapes could work).

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html

Comment: @mpapec yes, it could help parse the RHS, e.g. the `values` what contains espaced quotes or spaces. But the probelm is how to break the string into `key='values...'` part, my `m/regex/` fails. Could you show an simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Text::ParseWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords) as mpapec suggested:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my $string = q{key1="value1 value2" key2="va3" key4 key5=val5 key6='val6' key7='val x\'y zzz'};

my @words = shellwords $string;

my %parsed;
foreach my $word (@words) {
    my ($key, $values) = split /=/, $word, 2;

    $parsed{$key} //= [];
    push @{ $parsed{$key} }, $_ for shellwords $values;
}

print Dumper \%parsed;
```

#### Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'key1' => [
                      'value1',
                      'value2'
                    ],
          'key2' => [
                      'va3'
                    ],
          'key4' => [],
          'key5' => [
                      'val5'
                    ],
          'key6' => [
                      'val6'
                    ],
          'key7' => [
                      'val',
                      'x\'y',
                      'zzz'
                    ]
        };
```

Note that for consistency, I assigned keys without values an empty array instead of `undef`. I think this will make the data structure easier to use.

Also note that I called `shellwords` twice. I did this to remove the backslashes from escaped quotes, so that

```
key7='val x\'y zzz'
```

gets split into

```
val x'y zzz
```

instead of

```
val x\'y zzz
```

(The backslash in `x\'y` in the output above is added by `Data::Dumper`; there's no backslash in the variable itself.)

Comment: GREAT solution. Really the ParseWords could contain more examples. Beginner as me has troubles fully underdtand it. Reading the doc i don't get the idea that the `shellwords` will break the string to key=value pairs. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To fix your current issue, you can setup an alteration to handle backslashes in a special way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my $parsed;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next if m/\A\s*#/;
    while (
        m{
        (\w+)
        (?:
            \s* = \s* 
            (["'])
            ( (?: (?!\2)[^\\] | \\. )* )
            \2
        )?
    }gx
        )
    {
        my $k = $1;
        if ($2) {
            ( my $val = $3 ) =~ s/\\(.)/$1/g;    # Unescape backslashes
            $parsed->{$k} = [ split /\s+/, $val ];    # Split words
        } else {
            $parsed->{$k} = undef;
        }
    }
    dd $parsed;
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
key1="value1 value2" key2 key3="val3"
key1='value1 "value2"' key2 key3='val3'
key1='value1 i\'m' key2 key3="val3"
```

Outputs:

```
{ key1 => ["value1", "value2"], key2 => undef, key3 => ["val3"] }

{ key1 => ["value1", "\"value2\""], key2 => undef, key3 => ["val3"] }

{ key1 => ["value1", "i'm"], key2 => undef, key3 => ["val3"] }
```

There are still other issues to take into account, but perhaps this will help you get further along.

Comment: This definitely helps as an good starting point, especially because probably here isn't any CPAN module what can handle this task. :( So, remains the regex solution, and i need split the string before each `\b\w+` what aren't inside the quotes to divide LHS=RHS. Going to study your solution. Thanx! :)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something based on Parser::MGC. Your examples look like a nice simple loop on

```
my $key = $self->token_ident;
$self->expect( '=' );
my $value = $self->token_string;
```